# Curious folder on the root of volume on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows

We have just set up a new windows 2008 R2 server with three separate raid arrays as drives C:, F: and I:. After installing all the windows updates and Trend Micro anti virus, we see at the root of our F: volume a folder named "c323e2a243c313f307e247fd" containing only an empty folder named "Sandbox". It has unique security applied

Where might it have come from? And what if we delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These folders are often created by Windows when applying updates.  I have seen them created both on C: drives and on additional drives.  I wouldn't delete it, but then I don't like to delete anything unless I have to.  A hard lesson learned.